# How to speed up sendkeys() in Internet Explorer when using Selenium-Webdriver 2.0?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently testing on Internet Explorer 8.  My script types in a username and password and logs into a website.

The problem is that the sendkeys() function takes forever to finish.  The username is only 8 characters long, but takes about 30 - 40 seconds to enter in.  As my tests expand, this is going to translate into tests that take forever to complete.

How can I speed up this operation?  I'd prefer not to use native javascript to enter in data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to optimize / speed up the sending of data to a UI with Protractor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689090/is-there-any-way-to-optimize-speed-up-the-sending-of-data-to-a-ui-with-protrac)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have two options for entering text in fields:

1. sendkeys()
2. javascript

The first isn't working for you, and you've decided against the second for whatever reason, which leaves just one other thing you could try - a different IE configuration.  Try turning protected mode off for all zones (or on if you have it off), sometimes that can make a difference for performance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the sendKeys work, I used the following method:

- use JavaScript to set the value of the input but leave out the last character
- use `sendKeys` to enter the missing character

An example of entering an IBAN `CH1709000000147117606` looks like this

```
    browser.executeAsyncScript(function(callback){
        document.getElementsByName("kontoNummer")[0].value = "CH170900000014711760";
        callback();
    }).then(page.kontoNummer.sendKeys('6'));
```

The reason why the last character is still entered via `sendKeys` is because it sets the focus on the form element and allows for correct event triggering